# Hibernate creating same PK?

Tags: hibernate, spring

I have the following situation: Say I have an entity "Event" that contains a Set of "Place" entity objects with a @OneToMany mapping.

```
@Entity
public class Event {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=Generation.AUTO)
   @JoinColumn
   private Long id = 0L;

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=Fetch.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="event_id")    
   @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade (value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
   private Set<Place> places = new HashSet<Place>();
}

@Entity
public class Place {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @JoinColumn
   private Long id = 0L;

   private String name;

   private Long placeId = 0L;
}
```

I am also running with Spring 3.X and using AnnotationSessionFactoryBean as my session factory. Both entities are listed properly in the annotatedClasses property of this class.

I create (through my Web app) a new event with a place and save. There is a new entry in both the Event and Place table as expected. Next I create another new event with the same place as the first event. This time when I attempt to save I get a NonUniqueObjectException. The primary key of the first place is being noted as the issue. It appears that a "new" id is not being created for the second place. In other words it is reusing the ID. I am expecting a second row to be created in the place table but it is not.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "Next I create another new event with the same place as the first event" - what does this mean?  Show us the code to demonstrate what you're doing.

Comment: You contradict yourself in your question: you first say that you create a new event with the same place, and then say that you expect a second place to be created. Tell us what you're trying to do and show us the code doing it.

Comment: Say I create a Event #1 with Place #1. Next I create Event #2 with Place #1. I would expect the following in my DB from the first event creation: In the event table one row with id=1 and in the place table one row with id=1 and event_id = 1. After the second event is created I expect the following in the DB: two rows in the event table, one with id=1 and the other with id=2 and 2 rows in the place table, one with id=1 and event_id=1 and the second with id=2 and event_id=2. I am really simplifying the objects here since I cannot put the "full" objects here.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try replacing:

```
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=Generation.AUTO)
```

with

```
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Comment: It actually is GenerationType.AUTO. I mistyped. I will fix in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If an event can occurs at many place you will need a `OneToMany` association between `Event` and `Place` entity. With a `OneToMany` association you can't reuse a `Place` between `Event`
you would have to use a `ManyToMany` association to do that.

**Standard** `OneToMany` bidirectional association.

```
    @Entity
    public class Event
    {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="event", orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<Place> places = new HashSet<Place>();
    }

    @Entity
    public class Place
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        private String name;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="event_id")
        private Event event;

    }
...
    //create event#1 and a place #1Event event1 = new Event();
    Place place1 = new Place();
    event1.getPlaces().add(place1);
    place1.setEvent(event1);
    entitymanager.persist(event1);


    //create event#2 and place #2 and place #3
    Event event2 = new Event();
    Place place2 = new Place();
    Place place3 = new Place();

    event2.getPlaces().add(place2);
    place1.setEvent(event2);
    event2.getPlaces().add(place3);
    place3.setEvent(event2);
    entitymanager.persist(event2);
```

See the Hibernate Reference documentation section [2.2.5. Mapping entity associations/relationship](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association)  for more information on mapping association between entity.